# Animating bitmap image in android

Tags: android, animation, bitmap, geometry

I have created a bitmap image which is a circle and than as I wanted to animate it so i converted it into bitmapdrawable and than added it to animation drawable..But due to this the circle shaped has changed to oval shape...

So what should I do ?

Is there any other method to animate only the bitmap file. ?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

no, you can not animate the `bitmap` itself with the `android animation framwork`. You can directly animate `View`s or `ViewGroup`s and all the classes that derives from `View` and `ViewGroup`.

Call `view` the `ImageView` that contains the bitmap.

```
TranslateAnimation slide = new TranslateAnimation(view.getX(), view.getX()  + 100, view.getY(), view.getY()  + 100 );   
slide.setDuration(1000);
view.startAnimation(slide)
```

that should translate the `ImageView` by `100px` from the current position

Comment: so what should I do to animate the circle which i have created using bitmap ??

Comment: put the bitmap inside a view, and animate the view itself. I will edit my answer with an example

Answer (score 5):

If you're using Canvas, I'd suggest holding a pointer to the current Bitmap and loading all other Bitmaps into an array.

Say,

```
Bitmap[] frames = new Bitmap[10] //10 frames
Bitmap frame[0] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.circlefram1);
Bitmap frame[1] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.circlefram2);
...
```

Select the currentFrame by pointing at the frame you're interested in.

```
Bitmap currentBitmap = frame[3]; // 4th frame
```

So when you call drawBitmap(currentBitmap) it will only draw the frame you are interested in. You can change the bitmap every so many frames, by assigning an fps to the frame animation.

If you just want to scale or rotate the bitmap (rotating a circle?), the best way to resize a bitmap is using createScaledBitmap, and rotating using a matrix.

For Scaling, you load any bitmap into memory like this

```
Bitmap circleBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.circle);
```

If you would like the circle (or any bitmap) rescaled you would do something like this:

```
Bitmap scaledCircle = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(circleBitmap, dstWidth, dstHeight, filter);
```

Where dstWidth and dstHeight are the target destination width and height, which you can previously calculate by scaling the original width and height.

```
int scaledHeight = circleBitmap.getHeight()/2;
int scaledWidth = circleBitmap.getWidth()/2;
```

And finally you would normally draw this Bitmap using a canvas like this

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap)
```

For rotating, create a Matrix

```
Matrix mat;
mat.postRotate(degrees); // Rotate the matrix
Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalBitmap, x, y, width, height, mat, filter);
```

and finally

```
canvas.drawBitmap(rotatedBitmap);
```

Keep in mind Canvases are slow for games or anything real-time!

Hope it helps.