# Unable to Animate curve according to Time

Tags: android, animation, shapes, curve

I have one array of xy points of the screen.
Now I want to animate this points with respect to different different time.
For this i have created Custom View, I am able able to animate the curve with this below method inside onDraw. Where IMaxAnimationStep is currently set to 400 , iCurStep is set to 0

```
public void animate(Canvas canvas){
    Matrix mxTransform = new Matrix();
    if (iCurStep <= iMaxAnimationStep) {
        pm.getMatrix(fSegmentLen * iCurStep, mxTransform,
                PathMeasure.POSITION_MATRIX_FLAG + PathMeasure.TANGENT_MATRIX_FLAG);
        mxTransform.preTranslate(-bmSprite.getWidth() / 2, -bmSprite.getHeight() / 2);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmSprite, mxTransform, null);

        iCurStep++; //advance to the next step
        invalidate();
    } else {
        iCurStep = 0;
    }
}
```

But how can i animate the curve with respect to time
Please help and thanks in adv.

Comment: Did you look around in SO like, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11482955/animating-bitmap-image-in-android

Comment: @Raviprakash I tried but I want smooth animation . So I think making a custom view is best apporach.